# C++ meta-programming doxygen documentation

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I am documenting some code which uses meta-programming heavily, for example:

```
 template<rysq::type A, rysq::type B, rysq::type C, rysq::type D, class Transform>
 struct Kernel<meta::braket<A,B,C,D>, Transform,
               typename boost::enable_if<
                   quadrature<meta::braket<A,B,C,D>, Transform> >::type>
 : Eri <Transform> {
```

what is a good way to document such construct using doxygen?

Comment: I think you need to write proper documentation, using  a word-processor. If I came across the usual doxy generated docs (no matter how much extra annotation you add) for stuff like this, I think I would probably say "no thanks". But then I'd probably say it anyway :-)

Comment: This is exactly why I stay away from template metaprogramming in C++. It's ridiculous.

Comment: @You there is not a better way to do it, not in any language

Comment: @aaa  That seems extremely unlikely, depending on what you mean by "better", of course.

Comment: @aaa: Do you know about the `@tparam` doxygen command?

Comment: @GMan yes, however it becomes messy with specialization.
@Neil I wanted to keep source code and documentation together, so I wanted to go with doxygen (its internal details)

Comment: @aaa: Well, could you give a full example of some meta-programming utility you'd like doxygened?

Comment: @GMan sorry for late.
in above sample I would like to document template specialization, preferably without copy pasting actual arguments (that would be messy).  does it make sense?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to show what doxygen is currently outputting, and what you'd like it to output, the people can hone in on any doxygen settings that might get you closer to your goal.  As is, the question is too vague.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use preprocessor macros. Here's an example from [the not-yet-official Boost.XInt library](http://www.boostpro.com/vault/index.php?action=downloadfile&filename=xint.zip) (presently queued for review for inclusion in Boost):

```
#ifdef BOOST_XINT_DOXYGEN_IGNORE
    // The documentation should see a simplified version of the template
    // parameters.
    #define BOOST_XINT_INITIAL_APARAMS ...
    #define BOOST_XINT_CLASS_APARAMS ...
    #define BOOST_XINT_CLASS_BPARAMS other
    #define BOOST_XINT_APARAMS ...
    #define BOOST_XINT_BPARAMS other
#else
    #define BOOST_XINT_INITIAL_APARAMS \
        class A0 = parameter::void_, \
        class A1 = parameter::void_, \
        class A2 = parameter::void_, \
        class A3 = parameter::void_, \
        class A4 = parameter::void_, \
        class A5 = parameter::void_
    #define BOOST_XINT_CLASS_APARAMS class A0, class A1, class A2, class A3, \
        class A4, class A5
    #define BOOST_XINT_APARAMS A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5
    #define BOOST_XINT_CLASS_BPARAMS class B0, class B1, class B2, class B3, \
        class B4, class B5
    #define BOOST_XINT_BPARAMS B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5
#endif
```

Use the `#define`d macro names instead of the template parameters, everywhere you need them, like so:

```
/*! \brief The integer_t class template.

This class implements the standard aribitrary-length %integer type.

[...lots more documentation omitted...]
*/
template<BOOST_XINT_INITIAL_APARAMS>
class integer_t: virtual public detail::integer_t_data<BOOST_XINT_APARAMS>,
    public detail::nan_functions<detail::integer_t_data<BOOST_XINT_APARAMS>::
    NothrowType::value, // ...lots more base classes omitted...
{
    // ...etcetera
```

And put lines like these in the Doxyfile:

```
PREDEFINED             = BOOST_XINT_DOXYGEN_IGNORE

EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = BOOST_XINT_INITIAL_APARAMS \
                         BOOST_XINT_CLASS_APARAMS \
                         BOOST_XINT_CLASS_BPARAMS \
                         BOOST_XINT_APARAMS \
                         BOOST_XINT_BPARAMS
```

The result is that Doxygen sees either "..." or "other" for the template parameters, and the compiler sees the real ones. If you describe the template parameters in the documentation for the class itself, then the user of the library will only need to see them in the one place that he's likely to look for them; they'll be hidden everywhere else.

As an additional advantage to this design, if you ever need to make changes to the template parameter lists, you only need to change them in the macro definitions and the functions that actually use the changed parameters. Everything else will adapt automatically.

Comment: I hate to add additional macros/code just for doxygen, as if writing the documentation comments wouldn't be enough. Hope they will support templates soon.

Comment: For library code, the convenience of having all the documentation at the user's fingertips in a nicely formatted manner outweighs my personal inconvenience of having to add the macros and code. YMMV. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is my take on it:

```
///
/// \defgroup Kernel Kernel
///
/// \brief Kernel does this and that
/// \{

/// \brief Kernel template class brief description.
template<Braket,Transform,Boolean>
struct Kernel
{};

/// \brief Kernel partial template specialization brief description.
///
/// More detailed description...<br>
/// Partially specializes Kernel with meta::braket<A,B,C,D\>.<br>
/// If quadrature<meta::braket<A,B,C,D\>, Transform\> is true then enable
/// this algorithm, otherwise enable this other algorithm.<br>
/// Inherits privately from template class Eri<Transform\><br>
/// \tparam A           template parameter A of type rysq::type, documentation and concepts
/// \tparam B           template parameter B of type rysq::type, documentation and concepts
/// \tparam C           template parameter C of type rysq::type, documentation and concepts
/// \tparam D           template parameter D of type rysq::type, documentation and concepts
/// \tparam Transform   template parameter class Transform documentation and concepts
/// \see Kernel\<Braket,Transform,Boolean\>
/// \see Eri
/// \see meta::braket
/// \see quadrature
#ifdef DOXY
// This is the documentation version
template<A,B,C,D,Transform>
struct Kernel<Braket,Transform,Boolean>
#else
// This is what gets compiled
template<rysq::type A, rysq::type B, rysq::type C, rysq::type D, class Transform>
struct Kernel<meta::braket<A,B,C,D>, Transform,typename boost::enable_if<quadrature<meta::braket<A,B,C,D>, Transform> >::type>
#endif
: Eri <Transform> {};

/// \}
```

Don't forget to add DOXY in the PREDEFINED section of Doxygen's preprocessor.

I usually prefer to hide implementation details from the user of my code, so I change what Doxygen sees.
In this case, you will find all your specializations under one group, the Kernel group, and under the class list, all specializations will be grouped together and won't have a very long and un-comprehensible name.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the solution with additional macros/code, like [the swine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140976/the-swine).

Here is my solution based on a post-processing of the HTML pages generated by Doxygen.

It is a python script which works under Linux. It suppresses all the "<...>" in Template Classes and Structures Reference pages, and also in their "List of all members pages".

The little and less invasive "template<...>" before each documented method remains.

Run the script with the "html/" directory (where the documentation was generated) as argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import sys
import re

def processFile( fileName):

  f = open( fileName, 'r')

  content = f.read();

  f.close();

  regex = re.compile( "(&lt;.*&gt;).*(Template Reference|Member List)")

  match = re.search( regex, content)

  if not match:
    return

  toRemove = match.group(1)

  regex = re.compile(toRemove)

  content = re.sub( regex, "", content)

  f = open( fileName, 'w')

  f.write( content)

  f.close()


path = sys.argv[1]

finder = subprocess.Popen(["find", path, "-name", "class*.html", "-o", "-name", "struct*.html"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

(files, junk) = finder.communicate()

files = files.splitlines()

print files

for fname in files:
  if fname == "":
continue
  processFile(fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

The meta-programming seems to implement maths. I would write the describing mathematical formulas with latex escapes in the doxygen documentation.

Comment: hi. I may not made myself clear, I need to document programming logic, rather than mathematical description.

Comment: @aaa I'd say you need to document both.

Comment: @aaa What programming logic remains the in shown fragment when you strip it of C++ and meta-programming technicialities?

Comment: what do you mean?  I am not following quite

Comment: @aaa I am not well enough versed in template meta-programming to see programming logic in the shown fragment. Never mind. I should better leave this to the experts.