# Documenting SFINAE overloaded functions with Doxygen

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, doxygen, sfinae

I'm trying to document the following SFINAE overloaded functions (both of them) with *Doxygen 1.8.11*:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value, int >::type = 0>
auto func(T x);

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int >::type = 0>
auto func(T x);
```

However the generated documentation contains only the first occurrence.

**Is there any way to document multiple SFINAE overloaded functions in doxygen?**

Comment: conditional preprocessor directives with alternate signatures for doxygen and real compilation I'm afraid :/

Comment: it's so frustrating that in 2016 you still have no proper tools to generate documentation for a C++ standard from 2011

Comment: see this question and the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435225/c-meta-programming-doxygen-documentation