# How to document "enable_if" functions with Doxygen

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

In a class `Foo` I have the following template functions :

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    template <typename T>
    static typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>, T*>::type allocate();
    template <typename T>
    static typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>, T*>::type allocate();
};
```

There is two declarations, but, for the user, only one function.

**What is the usual way to document this kind of declaration with Doxygen ?**

Idea #1 :

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    /** \brief This function throws a runtime error */
    template <typename T>
    static typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>, T*>::type allocate();
    /** \brief This function allocates an instance of the given type */
    template <typename T>
    static typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>, T*>::type allocate();
};
```

Idea #2 :

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    /** \brief This function allocates an instance of the given type if not abstract, throws an exception instead */
    template <typename T>
    static typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>, T*>::type allocate();
    template <typename T>
    static typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>, T*>::type allocate();
};
```

Comment: No chance to document template stuff in general with doxygen. Any kind of specialization is not handled in a expected fashion. Have you found a way to comment on template parameters at all? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435225/c-meta-programming-doxygen-documentation?rq=1

Comment: @Klaus : For the moment, I have no other problem to document template functions with Doxygen. Maybe I didn't do complex things with templates before today...

Comment: For your example, instead of two overloads, you could just have one and then do `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(!boost::is_abstract<T>::value, "T must be concrete")` in it. This will generate a compile error if the requirements for `T` are not met, which is preferable to a runtime exception. The C++11 equivalent would be `static_assert(!std::is_abstract<T>::value, "T must be concrete")`, and in C++17: `static_assert(!std::is_abstract_v<T>, "T must be concrete")`.

Comment: @EmileCormier actually, I need a runtime check in my context because the type is only known at runtime and `new T` must be called by `allocate` if not abstract. During the execution, the other function will never be called (some check before), but the compiler doesn't know it and want to write the branch.

Comment: @Caduchon Ah, now I understand. You could use _tagged dispatching_ in that case. See the bottom part of my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this in terms of `std::enable_if`, but it should work just as well with `boost::enable_if`.

You can use macros that wrap `enable_if` and define them differently whether Doxygen is running or not.

In your Doxyfile, add the following to your configuration:

```
PREDEFINED = GENERATING_DOXYGEN

EXPAND_AS_DEFINED = ENABLE_IF \
                    ENABLED_TYPE
```

In your C++ project, define the following macros:

```cpp
#ifdef GENERATING_DOXYGEN
#define ENABLE_IF(cond)
#define ENABLED_TYPE(T, cond) T
#else
#define ENABLE_IF(cond) typename std::enable_if<(cond)>::type
#define ENABLED_TYPE(T, cond) typename std::enable_if<(cond), T>::type
#endif
```

You may then use the macros as follows:

```cpp
class Foo
{
  public:
    /** \brief Throws a runtime error
        \tparam T An abstract type
        \detail Only participates in overload resolution
                when std::is_abstract<T>::value==true */
    template <typename T>
    static ENABLED_TYPE(T*, std::is_abstract<T>::value) allocate();

    /** \brief Allocates an instance of the given type
        \tparam T A concrete type
        \detail Only participates in overload resolution
                when std::is_abstract<T>::value==false */
    template <typename T>
    static ENABLED_TYPE(T*, !std::is_abstract<T>::value) allocate();
};
```

The `ENABLED_TYPE` macros will expand to the undecorated return type (in your case, `T*`) when Doxygen is running. When compiling, the macros will expand to `std::enable_if<cond, T>::type` to perform SFINAE.

Instead of `ENABLE_IF`, you may want to name the macro `REQUIRES` to make your code a bit more readable. You may also want to prefix your macros with the name of your project to avoid clashing with macros defined in other libraries or in whatever super-project may want to consume your project.

---

What you can also do is have a single public function, and then use *tag dispatching* for your two cases:

```cpp
class Foo
{
  public:
    /** \brief Allocates an instance of the given type
        \tparam T Must be a concrete type (checked at run time) */
    template <typename T>
    static T* allocate()
    {
      do_allocate(std::is_abstract<T>());
      // ...
    }

  private:
    template <typename T>
    T* do_allocate(std::false_type)
    {
      return new T;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T* do_allocate(std::true_type)
    {
      throw std::runtime_error("T must be concrete");
    }
};
```

With C++17, you could simply do `if constexpr`:

```cpp
class Foo
{
  public:
    /** \brief Allocates an instance of the given type
        \tparam T Must be a concrete type (checked at run time) */
    template <typename T>
    static T* allocate()
    {
      if constexpr (std::is_abstract<T>())
      {
        throw std::runtime_error("T must be concrete");
      }
      else
      {
        return new T;
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution to the problem, though admittedly I'd absolutely *hate* to be in a codebase where people are wrapping otherwise visible/idiomatic uses of `enable_if` inside of macros, purely just so a third-party tool like doxygen can generate something decent. IMO code shouldn't be written strangely just to assist a tool.

Comment: You should also mention the version of doxygen you used.

Comment: @albert The Doxygen config options I used in my answer have been supported for over a decade.

Comment: @Human-Compiler This whole SFINAE business already *is* some strange-looking code to begin with. Hopefully C++20 constraints will improve things when it gains better support and adoption.

Comment: @EmileCormier it might be that the settings have been supported for over a decade but the underlying logic might have been wrong and has been corrected, so it is always good to mention the used version.